# In UE4's Blueprints, how do I activate something when the player looks at it?

Tags: game-mechanics, unreal-4, visibility-determination, blueprints

I want to make an object that activates when the player presses a button, then looks at it. How can I do this using Blueprints Visual Scripting?

Comment: See this article. What you are looking for is a RAYCAST. https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/HowTo/UseRaycasts/Blueprints/